# Unable to retrieve validation attributes (from my model) in my custom html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I developed my own custom htmlhelper for managing my radio buttons. No problems for generating basic html tag from my custom helper. But I have problems for injecting validation attributes in my html tag (client side unobtrusive validation). I used the htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(prefix) for retrieving validation attributes from my model (data annotations) but it doesn'work for my custom RequiredAttribute.

Here is a part of my view model:

```
public class MaterialEditNewViewModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    [CustomRequired]
    Public bool ADR { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is my CustomRequired:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{        
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        string translatedFieldName = UserResource.ResourceManager.GetString(name);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedFieldName))
            translatedFieldName = name;
        return string.Format(UserResource.FieldRequired, translatedFieldName);
    }   
}
```

Here is my custom html helper:

```
public static IHtmlString RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, string labelText)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string prefix = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        var validationAttributes = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(prefix); 

        object currentValue = metadata.Model;
        string property = metadata.PropertyName;

        // Build the radio button html tag 
        var htmlRadio = new TagBuilder("input");
        htmlRadio.GenerateId(property + value);
        htmlRadio.Attributes["type"] = "radio";
        htmlRadio.Attributes["name"] = property;
        htmlRadio.Attributes["value"] = Convert.ToString(value);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in validationAttributes)
        {
            htmlRadio.MergeAttribute(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
        } 

        if (object.Equals(currentValue, value))
        {
            htmlRadio.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
        }

        // Build the label html tag 
        var label = new TagBuilder("label");
        label.Attributes["for"] = htmlRadio.Attributes["id"];
        label.SetInnerText(labelText);

        // Return the concatenation of both tags 
        return new HtmlString(htmlRadio.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + label.ToString()
        );
    }
```

1. You have to know that my CustomRequired data annotation works for basic helper like @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ADR) but it doesn't work when used on custom htmlhelpers.
2. I know that when I use 'classic' data annotation like [Required] in my model I have no problems retrieving validation attributes BUT when using my CustomRequiredAttribute the GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes returns nothing!

Any idea why? If I'm not clear, don't hesitate to ask me to clarify.

I forgot to say that I use Entity Framework Code First with MVC3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [RequiredAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) doesn't implement the [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) interface you must register a custom adapter for your custom attribute. You could do this by adding the following line in `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(CustomRequiredAttribute), 
    typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter)
);
```

There are 2 ways to implement client side validation attributes:

- Have your custom validation attribute implement the `IClientValidatable` interface
- Register a custom adapter

The `RequiredAttribute` uses the second approach. It associates the `RequiredAttributeAdapter` to all required attributes. But since you have derived from the RequiredAttribute, your custom attribute no longer has the adapter. So you need to register it in `Application_Start`.

Comment: Thank you, it works pretty well. Just one question: I use my CustomRequired on 2 others fields in my view but not through a customm helper but with Html.TextBoxFor and for these elements I didn't needed to register my custom adapter in order to have the client side validation. Can you explain?